# listen to tap and dragged value and function accordingly

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

How should I create a custom page transition which listens to tap and swipe/drag even?.Suppose, if the page is dragged right/left (while still holding), then drag/slide the page to the value of swipe/threshold. And when the tap is released, if value is equal to or greater than the center of the page or maximum threshold, slide to the next page (link), or else slide back to its original position. [Example](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Swipe_status.html). I would like to apply it in my jquery mobile app. An example demo would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JavaScript library, such as [HammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) for easy touch gesture handling. [Swipe](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Could you answer me with a example.

Answer (score 1):

Also TouchSwipe jquery plugin is commendable, because it's easy to implement and provides swipe, pinch, touch and threshold events and triggers:
https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

Comment: Can you answer me with an example.

Comment: You did just find an [example](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Swipe_status.html) for TouchSwipe Plugin.